# Is it acceptable to use global in this case? Is there a more pythonic way to achieve the same result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

The code below works, but I see everyone discourage the use of global variables. I see how it can cause problems, so is there a better/more pythonic way to do what the code below does?

This code is for a chat moderation bot. As soon as a message is received bot checks if the filter is enabled or not and proceeds with the filtering if the boolean below is set to true.

```
filter_is_enabled = True


def toggle_filter():
    global filter_is_enabled
    filter_is_enabled = not filter_is_enabled
    if filter_is_enabled:
        bot.say('Chat filter enabled.')
    else:
        bot.say('Chat filter disabled.')


def check_message(message):
    if filter_is_enabled:
        # proceed with the filtration
    else:
        # proceed without filtering
```

Comment: Why donot you pass it as a parameter and return it?

Comment: As far as I know discord.py library doesn't allow calling check_message function or a function within the check_message function. I simplified the code posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class to maintain state:

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, is_enabled=True):
        self.is_enabled = is_enabled

    def toggle(self):
        self.is_enabled = not self.is_enabled
        print('is_enabled? %s' % self.is_enabled)

class Main(object):

    filter = Filter()

    @classmethod
    def check_message(cls):
        if cls.filter.is_enabled:
            print('Chat filter enabled.')
        else:
            print('Chat filter disabled.')

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        # demo
        cls.filter.toggle()
        cls.check_message()
        cls.filter.toggle()
        cls.check_message()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main.run()
```